# Facebook fql query by php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

How to run facebook fql query by php sdk ??

below Is the fql that I want to run

```
fql?q=select subscriber_id from subscription where    subscribed_id = 100004769612804 AND subscriber_id=me()&access_token=
```

& after that I want to show error to my users who don't do follow this

Comment: Is this example helping you out? 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the documentations here . Very simple to understand.

[Facebook Developers Guides - FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

Comment: you can use the php code to catch exceptions and let your users know. See the api docs for error handling.